# Converting BigQuery string to datetime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a bq table withhas a column `timestamp` as a string, with format `20090630 16:36:23:880`, how can I convert it to a proper timestamp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parse_datetime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%E3S', '20090630 16:36:23.880')
```

Comment: Hi, the format on microseconds is different from `:23.880`, but it's `:23:880`. I am trying this:


    SELECT
        parse_datetime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S:%E3S',
        timestamp) as timestamp,
        bid,
        ask
    FROM
        `my_table`
    LIMIT
        10


But I keep on having a conversion error.

Comment: I see. I thought it was a typo in your question. Will check again shortly ...

Comment: maybe I need to convert the string to use the '.' and then convert ?

Comment: that would be the direction I would go with :o)

Comment: Anyway it's not clear why it does not recognise the format I present ...

Comment: because expected (correct) format is `:23.880`

Comment: Ah, so %E3S is seconds PLUS microseconds... I see

Comment: so, to address this "wrong" format - try this `parse_datetime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%E3S', regexp_replace('20090630 16:36:23:880', r' (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(:)(\d*)', r'\1.\3'))` as a quick "fix"

Comment: Syntax error: Illegal input character "\\" at [2:70] (The first \ in \d list).

Comment: i tested it before pasting into comments! so please make sure you use it exactly as it is in my comments

Comment: Oh, I retried one more time and it worked, thanks !